# Mapping values in json-schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, fastify

So JSON schema is defined [here](https://www.w3.org/2019/wot/json-schema) and I'm particularly using [fluent-json-schema](https://github.com/fastify/fluent-json-schema) implementation by Fastify team.

I used [Joi](https://github.com/sideway/joi) for validation in an Express app that I'm porting to Fastify.

I use a lot of validation for checkboxes and choice radio inputs. I would like to know how to assign the two boolean values to arbitrary string values

```js
// So this is possible in Joi but not in `fluent-json-schema`
S.boolean().truthy('on').falsy('off').default(false)
```

Not only for booleans, it would be nice to have the possibility to map values as this is really handy in front and back architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to map values using a preValidation callback.

```
function prevalidation_1(request, reply, done) {
    request.body = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.keys(request.body).map((key) => {
            if(key === 'exact') {
                const isTrue = request.body[key] == 'on' ? true : false
                return [key, isTrue]
            } else {
                return [key, request.body[key]]
            }
        })
    )
    done()
}
```

```
// Example secured route
fastify.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/upload',
    preHandler: fastify.auth([
        fastify.verifyJWT,
    ]),
    preValidation: prevalidation_1,
    handler: (req, reply) => {
        req.log.info('Upload route')
        const { body } = req
        reply.send({ hello: body.exact })
    }
})
```